# Formik not updating select value

Tags: reactjs, formik

Hi I am trying to create a select form using Formik. But when I select a field the state does not get updated. Could someone please help me in fixing it. Here is my code:

```
                      <Form.Control
                        as="select"
                        value={values.company}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        isValid={touched.company && !errors.company}
                        isInvalid={Boolean(touched.company && errors.company)}
                      >
                        <option>Select Company</option>
                        {companyArray}
                      </Form.Control>
                      <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                        {errors.company}
                      </Form.Control.Feedback>
```

Comment: How did you implement `handleChange`? is it something like `({target: {name, value}}) => setState(state => ({...state, values: {...state.values, [name]: value }}))`?

Comment: Its a functional Component